# Salesforce Platform Event Trigger

Tags: events, triggers, apex, platform

I have created this trigger that is supposed ot make a POST to an external service. The trigger is meant to fire when a new platform event is created. It does not seem to fire though.

Can anyone see a problem with my code that would stop it from triggering? The platform event is created through a record triggered flow however I have tried executing anonymous script in dev console but no trigger.

```
  trigger SendtoFSPTrigger on Work_Order_Dispatch__e (after insert) {
    for (Work_Order_Dispatch__e event : Trigger.New) {
```

I have created the correct platform event but the apex trigger wasn't called.